# Microk8s on Window11 not install/uninstalling correctly

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, microk8s, multipass

I am having problems after uninstalling microk8s and reinstalling the software. The first time, it was able to find and establish a connection to Hyper-V which was configured and working nicely. I accidentally uninstalled the software thinking that it was a different machine. After reinstalling the application, I am not able to get the microk8s to start:

```
C:\Users\xxxx>microk8s start
start failed: The following errors occurred:
microk8s-vm: timed out waiting for response
An error occurred with the instance when trying to start with 'multipass': returned exit code 2.
Ensure that 'multipass' is setup correctly and try again.
```

Actions taken:

1. Uninstalled MicroK8s
2. Uninstalled Multipass (v1.7.3)
3. Deleted microk8s-vm from Hyper-V
4. Installed microk8s using "microk8s-installer.exe"

I am pretty sure that I am missing a clean up step somewhere.

Comment: Confused the same Question

Comment: Let me go back and review where I am at with this.  If I found a solution or workaround I will post it last night or sometime tomorrow.  Do you have an option to set up your environment on a Windows 11 VM?  That will help in the short run.  I run into issues because I had a bunch of stuff set up on my PC already, thus conflicts.